# Incrementing React State stuck at 29

Tags: reactjs, floating-point, precision

I am trying to increment the value of a progress bar with a `setProgressBarValue` hook in React but it seems to be stuck at 29. Here is the code:

```
const updateProgress = (byAmount: number, totalCount: number) => {
    setProgressBarValue((oldProgressValue) => {
       // derive records currently downloaded from progress bar value
       const prevResolvedCount = Math.floor(oldProgressValue * totalCount);
       // add records just downloaded from this promise resolving
       const newResolvedCount = prevResolvedCount + byAmount;
       // set new percentage
       return newResolvedCount / totalCount;
    });
});
```

It's a progress bar for downloading records and so it increments the value one by one. Everything works fine but if you are uploading 50 or 100 records, it properly counts up until `newResolvedCount` hits 29 and is stuck there. It looks like the `oldProgressValue` is no longer updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while to figure this out but it was actually related to how Javascript handles floating-point numbers. When `oldProgressValue` is `0.29` and then `totalCount` is `100`, the result of `oldProgressValue * totalCount` above is not `29` but rather `28.999999999999996`. So the `Math.floor()` would always round it back down to 28 before it was incremented back to 29.

My solution was to not actually round the value until it was displayed in the spinner and leave the progress bar value as it was to not affect the math.